# Delete OrderItem Error

Tags: dmlexception, order, orderitem

When I try to delete an OrderItem from an Order, I am getting a DML Mixed Exception. However, I am not updating any other object.

Am I missing something?

```
@istest
private class TestDeleteOrderItemEntry {

@future
static void del(Id oli) {
    database.delete(oli);
    system.assertEquals(0, [SELECT Id FROM OrderItem].size());
}

static testMethod void testDelete(){

    Test.startTest();

    Account a = new Account(Name='TestAccount');
    insert a;

    Contract c = new Contract(AccountId=a.Id, Name='TestContract',StartDate=system.today().toStartOfMonth(),ContractTerm=30,Status='Draft');
    insert c;

    c.Status = 'Activated';
    update c;

    Pricebook2 pb = new Pricebook2(Name='TestPriceBook');
    insert pb;

    Product2 prod = new Product2(Name = 'TestProduct');
    insert prod;

    Order o = new Order(AccountId=a.Id,ContractId=c.Id,EndDate=system.now().addDays(1).date());
    o.EffectiveDate  = system.today();
    o.Status = 'Draft';
    o.Pricebook2Id = pb.Id;
    o.EndDate = system.today();
    insert o;

    PricebookEntry standardPrice = new PricebookEntry(
    Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(), Product2Id = prod.Id,
    UnitPrice = 10000, IsActive = true);
    insert standardPrice;

    PricebookEntry priceEntry = new PricebookEntry(
    Pricebook2Id = pb.Id, Product2Id = prod.Id,
    UnitPrice = 10000, IsActive = true, UseStandardPrice=true);        
    insert priceEntry;

    OrderItem item = new OrderItem(OrderId=o.Id, Quantity=1, UnitPrice=3, PriceBookEntryId=priceEntry.Id);
    insert item;

    del(item.Id);

    Test.stopTest();
}

}
```

Error:

```
15:10:59:712 FATAL_ERROR System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id 8027A0000008qQYQAY; 
            first error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted 
            after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa):
            CustomFieldDefinition, original object: OrderItem: []
```

Thanks,

Comment: My guess would be that even though you may only be deleting the orderItem  in your test class. There may be other events within the same transaction (such as a trigger) that is updating a setup object somewhere. And therefore causing a Mixed DML opperation to take place. Please check any trigger or your test class.

Comment: If @Himanshu is correct(which I think he is), your going to need to build in a atFuture

Comment: correct. that is the only option but he needs to first identify that place.

Comment: Thanks @Himanshu. I've added a futures function, but still get the same error? I have disabled all triggers and workflows.

Comment: What puzzles me is that its saying i've already updated an OrderItem List? I have no triggers at all on Order Products, nor do I on an Order. Weird.

Comment: the future method is defined in the test class?  or am i misreading something?

Comment: My observation may not be relevant to the error you are trying to solve but the future method execution won't be completed for sure until the `Test.stopTest()` is invoked.

Comment: Without seeing your test setup code, I suspect that everyone is going to be chasing a red herring. Those queries are running on data that came from someplace & how they were created may be at the root of the issue.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't mean to put you on a wild goose chase there, lets see if that is the issue.  These are setup objects, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/reference_objects_setup.htm..

Comment: Appreciate everyones feedback. I've updated the code to reflect what data I'm passing in. I've turned off all triggers and workflow rules. The future function executes AFTER the test, but still throws an exception. So something is still up. Thanks again for everybody's help.

Comment: Using System.runAs(user) makes the test pass, but still get the error live.

Comment: there is no reason why a testmethod should have to delete an sobject inserted  by the code via a future method

Answer (score 3):

The cause of the issue was a custom roll-up field on the Contract. Go Figure. I was SUMing the total order amounts across all orders for a certain contract.

To fix this issue, I created a custom formula field "TotalAmount2" on an Order. Then created a roll-up field across that custom field on the Contract.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I'm still confirming things but I think this fixed our error: "DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): CustomFieldDefinition, original object: OrderItem". Thank you for sharing! (FYI I up-voted this from -1 to 0 - not sure who would downvote this).